# How do I get my code to process a given minimum value AND a value if < than given minimum

Tags: java

I am a Java newbie and have been working on this program for about a month. My program is a graduation planner that shows the student how much time and money it would take to finish a college degree. I would like my program to be able to recognize that the minimum # of CUs could be < than 12 if the student only has 6 or so CUs left until graduation, but I also need it to recognize if I enter a letter or negative number which I somehow managed to pull off at the top of the code. I tried to use sum == sum which isn't giving me the desired output. I think I need to put the while (loop) somewhere in there.

```
package gradplanner13;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradPlanner13 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean loop = true;
    System.out.println("Enter the individual CUs for your remaining courses. Enter 0 when done entering your individual CUs.");

    while (loop) {
        System.out.print("Enter CUs for individual course then press enter: ");

        if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Only positive numbers are valid inputs.  Please try again. ");
            continue;
        }

        if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Only postive numbers are valid inputs.  Please try again.");
            continue;
        }

        int check = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        if (check == 0) {
            loop = false;
            continue;
        } else if (check < 0) {
            System.out.println("CU values must be positive.  Try again.");
            continue;
        }
        array.add(check);

    }
    for (Integer CUs : array) {
        sum += CUs;
    }

    System.out.println("Total number of CUs for all courses: " + sum);

    double rounded = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("How many CUs you are planning to take each term: ");
        rounded = input.nextInt();

        if (sum == sum) {
            break;
        }

        if (rounded < 12 || rounded > sum) {
            System.out.println("Take each term with a minimum of 12 CUs or the CUs you have left to complete your program if less than 12 : ");
        }

    } while (rounded < 12 || rounded > sum);

    double numTermsToCompletion = Math.ceil(sum / rounded);
    System.out.println("Number of terms to completion: " + numTermsToCompletion);
    System.out.println("Tuition cost based on number of terms to completion: $" + (numTermsToCompletion * 2890));
    System.out.println("Number of months to completion: " + (numTermsToCompletion * 6));

}

}
```

The below code is the section that I think I am having trouble with because I need it to recognize that sometime a student may not have the minimum (12) CUs left and I would like it to check to make sure the minimum is met or recognize that less than the minimum is left and still process the input.  I tried to reuse while (loop) cause I know that part of the program responds correctly when I try to enter a letter or negative number at the beginning of the code, but I obviously was not implementing the loop correctly when I tried to put it on the below code, the program runs but doesn't produce anything when it gets to that point in the code. It just runs and doesn't produce any errors. In summary, I would appreciate some assistance getting my code to realize that a student may not have the minimum CUs left (12) and may need < than that to graduate, but also not accept negative numbers or letters as input.

```
do {
        System.out.print("How many CUs you are planning to take each term: ");
        rounded = input.nextInt();

        if (sum == sum) {
            break;
        }

        if (rounded < 12 || rounded > sum) {
            System.out.println("Take each term with a minimum of 12 CUs or the CUs you have left to complete your program if less than 12 : ");
        }

    } while (rounded < 12 || rounded > sum);
```

So I moved sum == sum and I am a little closer to where I need to be.  I still need to do some research because I am how getting the statement that tells me that I need to have a minimum of 12, but it still gives me the correct output.

```
do {
        System.out.print("How many CUs you are planning to take each term: ");
        rounded = input.nextInt();

        if (rounded < 12 || rounded > sum) {
            System.out.println("Take each term with a minimum of 12 CUs or the CUs you have left to complete your program if less than 12 : ");
        }

          if (sum == sum) {
            break;
        }

    } while (rounded < 12 || rounded > sum);
```

This is the output:

```
Total number of CUs for all courses: 8
How many CUs you are planning to take each term: 8
Take each term with a minimum of 12 CUs or the CUs you have left to complete    your program if less than 12 : 
Number of terms to completion: 1.0
Tuition cost based on number of terms to completion: $2890.0
Number of months to completion: 6.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Ok.  From the recommendations I have received, I rethought the process and rewrote some of the code and it works a lot better. The problem now is if the user enters 0 from the beginning, this is the output:

```
Enter the individual CUs for each individual remaining course. Enter 0 when done entering your individual CUs for each course.
Enter CUs for individual course then press enter: 0
Total number of CUs for all courses: 0
Number of terms to completion: 1
Tuition cost based on number of terms to completion: $2890
Number of months to completion: 6
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

If you have 0 CUs left, you shouldn't have any terms left.  It looks like I need to either change where my loop is false, or do something similar like I did here:

```
if (sum >= 12) {
    do {
        System.out.print("How many CUs you are planning to take each term?       Minimum of 12 CUs required per term:  ");
        numOfCUs = input.nextInt();
    } while (numOfCUs < 12);

    numTermsToGraduation = (int) Math.ceil(sum / (double) numOfCUs);
```

Below is the complete new code:

```
System.out.println("Enter the individual CUs for each individual remaining course. Enter 0 when done entering your individual CUs for each course.");

package gradplanner13;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GradPlanner13 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean loop = true;
    // Student enters the individual credits for each course remaining in their degree program
    System.out.println("Enter the individual CUs for each individual remaining course. Enter 0 when done entering your individual CUs for each course.");

    // loop checks to make sure inputs are positive numbers
    while (loop) {
        System.out.print("Enter CUs for individual course then press enter: ");

        if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Only positive numbers are valid inputs.  Please try again. ");
            continue;
        }

        if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Only postive numbers are valid inputs.  Please try again.");
            continue;
        }

        int check = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        if (check == 0) {
            loop = false;
            continue;
        } else if (check < 0) {
            System.out.println("CU values must be positive.  Try again.");
            continue;
        }

        // Calculates inputs from user
        array.add(check);

    }
    for (Integer CUs : array) {
        sum += CUs;
    }

    System.out.println("Total number of CUs for all courses: " + sum);

    int numOfCUs = 0;
    int numTermsToGraduation = 0;

    if (sum >= 12) {
        do {
            System.out.print("How many CUs you are planning to take each term? Minimum of 12 CUs required per term:  ");
            numOfCUs = input.nextInt();
        } while (numOfCUs < 12);

        numTermsToGraduation = (int) Math.ceil(sum / (double) numOfCUs);

    } else {
        numOfCUs = sum;
        numTermsToGraduation = 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Number of terms to completion: " + numTermsToGraduation);
    System.out.println("Tuition cost based on number of terms to completion: $" + (numTermsToGraduation * 2890));
    System.out.println("Number of months to completion: " + (numTermsToGraduation * 6));

}

}
```

Comment: sum == sum will always be true so the loop will break free right at that point, skipping the lines below.

Comment: @tk12 Ok.  So that makes me think that I need to move the sum == sum, which I tried.  I will edit the question so I can show what I did and the result it gave me.

Comment: plus one for using Ant :)

Comment: As long as that `sum == sum` with a break statement stays there, the loop will only loop once, hence losing its point of being a loop. You need to rethink your way of approaching to this.

Comment: if sum == sum, I need it to break out of the loop and run the rest of the program because I don't need to check to see if it is < 12 because I know it is < 12.  If sum doesn't equaI sum, I need it to continue through the loop and make sure it is > 12. I agree with your advice of rethinking my way of approaching this.  I need to do more Java reading and research.  I appreciate all of your feedback thus far.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could tell, you are trying to use "sum == sum" to tell you if the input value is an negative number or a letter. This is not correct, as sum==sum will always return true.

For checking if it is a number is positive, you should just use sum > 0.

As for checking if its actually a letter, and not a number, this is handled by your scanners when you check if the input is a number (hasNextInt).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `if (sum == sum) {...}` to error check the value of sum. That is not what you want to do, because it is always going to equate to true. What you want to do is use a `try {...} catch (InputMismatchException e) {...}`. In your case, it would be set up as follows:

```
...
System.out.println("Enter the individual CUs for your remaining courses. Enter 0 when done entering your individual CUs.");

int exception = 1;
while (exception = 1) {
    try {
        int someNum = input.nextInt();
        ... 
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        exception = 1;
        System.out.println("Please enter the correct data type!");
    }
}
...
```

At the first moment the `InputMismatchException` is thrown, the program will execute the code in the catch block.

Comment: This looks like it may be what I need.  I will try to implement soon and let everyone know how it turned out.  Thank you!

Comment: I decided to not go with this method because I found a better way to address what the professor was looking for.